# close an open folder programmatically in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I have searched but cannot find a function that can close a folder in vb.net. You can kill a running app by finding its handle/windows-title/id, then issuing process.kill() command, but the same does not work on folders. For example, suppose:

> C:\downloads\videos\

is open on my computer and I want to programmatically close it. How do I do that?

Comment: if you have a custom folder in your c disk the link c:downloads/videos is good else it will be C:\Users\myusername\Downloads\videos

Comment: I know. Just came up with the example folder for the question randomly.

Comment: Just realized I've used the wrong slash! editing my question to correct my mistake! Haha.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make a folder in your c disk names Test

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim myfolder As String = "C:\Test"
    Dim OpenFolder As Object = CreateObject("shell.application")
    For Each item In OpenFolder.Windows
        'ComboBox1.Items.Add(item.document.folder.self.Path)
        If item.document.folder.self.Path = myfolder Then
            item.Quit()
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: MSDN says CreateObject Creates and returns a reference to a COM object. Does that mean that the COM object is already there and running or is it that the function creates a new instance or a new object as a copy for our use?

Comment: CreateObject starts a class, then you can use the options of that class. Like run , quit etc

Answer (score 0):

I see your dilemma: open folders are just one part of the `explorer.exe` process. Killing that process would have undesirable side effects. To get around this, you have to send the right command to that process, instead of just killing it.

One place I would look to accomplish this is the [SendKeys](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.sendkeys.send(v=vs.110).aspx) class. You might be able to focus the window and send the Alt-F4 keys to close just that window.